# Problem with apt-get and CUDA installation

Tags: apt, nvidia, package-management, dpkg, cuda

I have a problem `An error occured, please run Packer Manager from the right click menu.`

```
sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-libraries-dev-10-1 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.0.168) but it is not installed
 cuda-samples-10-1 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.0.168) but it is not installed
 cuda-visual-tools-10-1 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.0.168) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution)
```

It started when I do all this thing below

I get a computer to work. I don't know what people do in that computer. I have account with administrator permissions. I have Ubuntu in version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:    bionic
```

I have a problem with CUDA installation. I need CUDA for molecular modelling. 
I installed CUDA this tutorial which works on two other computers.

[MEDIA=youtube]FK1y7XQuhp0[/MEDIA]

I did these steps:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential
gcc -v
make -v
lspci | grep -i nvidia
```

I dont see anything after I wrote this!!!!! I think that there is a problem with that.

Only this show me informations

```
sudo lshw -c video
[sudo] password for kuba:
  *-display UNCLAIMED      
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Then I wrote

```
gcc --version
```

Then installation from this site

[URL unfurl="true"]https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal[/URL]

Installation Instructions:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-10-1-local-10.1.168-418.67_1.0-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-<version>/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

I have errors installation, but it installed

I also added to bashrc

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then I check CUDA, but its not installed properly

```
$ ./deviceQuery
./deviceQuery Starting...
CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)
cudaGetDeviceCount returned 100
-> no CUDA-capable device is detected
Result = FAIL
```

I try to uninstall CUDA, but I can't find deinstallation files

[URL unfurl="true"]https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#runfile-uninstallation[/URL]

I try to use purge, but my apt-get isn't working

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove cuda-10.1
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cuda-libraries-dev-10-1 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.0.168) but it is not going to be installed
cuda-samples-10-1 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.0.168) but it is not going to be installed
cuda-visual-tools-10-1 : Depends: libcublas-dev (>= 10.2.0.168) but it is not going to be installed
nvidia-361 : Depends: nvidia-367 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

But this `apt --fix-broken install` didn't work

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cuda-repo-10-1-local-10.1.168-418.67/./libcublas-dev_10.2.0.168-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas_static.a', which is also in package nvidia-cuda-dev 9.1.85-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cuda-repo-10-1-local-10.1.168-418.67/./libcublas-dev_10.2.0.168-1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```